# Get user in path regex or pathlib Python

Tags: regex, lookbehind, pathlib

Given the examples

```
/foo/bar/foobar/user1/somethingelse
/foo/bar/barfoofoo/user2/blabla/blah/bluh
```

I'm trying to extract `user1` and `user2`. I know that both of their grandparents is `bar`, and I know that they're the 4th item in the path. The length after them is variable and their parent folder is also variable. I tried using lookbehind regexes, but because foobar and barfoofoo are of different length, I couldn't figure this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use split to solve it, for example:

```
cad = "/foo/bar/foobar/user1/somethingelse"
arr = cad.split('/')
print(arr[4]) #this is your username
```

Hope it helped !